# Can I control how often Gmail polls POP3 accounts for incoming mail?

Tags: gmail, mobile, pop3

I use Gmail to handle my mail, but it's mostly imported by Gmail from an external POP3 account.

Normally this works fine, but I;ve had some instances where Gmail has gone almost 24 hours without even trying to contact the POP3 server.

Now, on Gmail 'desktop', I can push the "refresh" button, and it will do it, but when I access Gmail from my mobile, the mobile version of the site (on Android 1.5, not that it matters) doesn't seem to have a way of doing this refresh. AFAIK I can't even access the POP3 settings.

How can I get Gmail to poll in a guaranteed timely fashion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com) just published a trick to [increase the frequency of the checks in Gmail](http://lifehacker.com/5580553/increase-the-frequency-gmail-checks-your-other-email-accounts-for-new-mail).

It's a bit of work to set it up, but essentially you need to ensure that your POP3 accounts frequently get new mail.

> Gmail bases its mail-fetching
>   frequency on how often it finds
>   messages in the account when it
>   checks; if the account only gets email
>   rarely, Gmail will check it once per
>   hour. From what I've been able to
>   tell, given a regular rate, Gmail's
>   mail fetcher seems to stabilize at
>   fetching twice as often as mail
>   appears in the account.

Comment: You can also use Google Calendar for this: Make a dummy calendar and an event that is repeated every X minutes. Set up an email reminder for this event.

Comment: Is there any "official" info on your affirmations?

Comment: Sadly, this trick stopped working sometime in 2013. Gmail seems to poll POP accounts ≈ every hour on average.

Comment: Phong, care to reference that claim?

Answer (score 7):

If you look under Google Labs, there's a feature called:

Refresh POP accounts

"Fetch messages from your POP accounts on demand by using the refresh link on top of the inbox."

Comment: Thanks, I was about to ask the same question, I like this solution better than the accepted one! Even when you mentioned it I read over the feature and had to use Ctrl + F to find it :o

Comment: No longer available.

Answer (score -1):

I've figured out a work around. Basically, I've written a script that sends an email to my email address every minute. Then, I have a filter in my gmail email to delete any email that has a special subject. It's up and running and working - gmail seems to be checking for emails every minute. If you'd like to be added to my list, send me an email: akshooty at, of course, my gmail account!﻿