# How can I get push email with multiple Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have a main (Google Apps Standard Edition) Gmail account which reads mail from 4 different Gmail accounts using POP3. The only problem I have is that it can sometimes take up to one hour before I get an email message, since the mailboxes are only checked about every hour.

How can I get the message immediately as it arrives, or at least very close to that (e.g. < 5 mins), while preserving the features I get by using POP3 access?

Here are the features I currently get by using POP3:

1. Robust auto tagging of Email based on the account they came from.
2. Account is kept alive.
3. Automatically chooses the correct address to reply from.

1: This is much more bullet-proof than simply creating a filter condition such as `to:user@gmail.com`, for several reasons. The first reason is that there are multiple valid aliases for each email address (e.g. `user+foo@gmail.com` or `u.ser@gmail.com` which would make the filter criteria complicated). The second reason is that I may have the mail account I'm reading reading mail from some other account (e.g. `user.account2@gmail.com`) so the `to` address would not even contain `user@gmail.com`. The same problem applies if I have forwarding set up to that account. Yet another reason is sometimes the sender will do really strange things like not having your email address in any of the `to` fields (e.g. when BCC'd), so the filter won't match. The point is, that when you use POP3 it is *guaranteed* to be tagged correctly. I have not found a consistent way to tag it any other way.

2: By logging in every hour or so, the account is kept from being inactivate due to Gmail automatically signing on.

3: When I click "reply" on a message, it automatically selects the correct `from` address (i.e. the email address that the email was sent to). This way I don't accidentally reveal any of my other addresses to the sender.

Comment: Be careful about that last part (not accidentally revealing other addresses).  In my experience, depending on the mail client a recipient is using, they can tell when you're "sending as" another address in gmail.  Google claimed to have fixed this, but I believe it is still the case.

Comment: This is no longer true.  As long as they are Google addresses (apps or gmail) you can authorize to send officially as the other address, not spoofed.
SEE: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?ctx=%67mail&answer=140634

And Technically it can be done for any SMTP that allows access via Login, the feature is called: Send through SERVERNAME.com SMTP servers (recommended for professional domains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the same thing with forwarding...

The trick is to forward to a unique plus-address instead of your real email address, and then creating a filter using the `deliveredto:` attribute which looks for this-plus address and applies a label matching emails.

I wrote [more detailed instructions on my blog](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/08/gmail-robust-tagging-of-forwarded-email.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply [increase the frequency your Gmail accounts are being checked](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/can-i-control-how-often-gmail-polls-pop3-accounts-for-incoming-mail).

This guarantees you have the exact same functionality, since it is still using POP3, just at a higher frequency.

The main problem with this method is that it involves a hack, which may be patched by Google in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use POP.  I use forwarding (from Google apps to gmail) and think that I nail all 3 of your issues:

1. To:@domain.com filter tags them all [EDIT] - May not work for gmail->gmail
2. Never had any issues of the account expiring.  Been doing this for at least 36months.
3. This happens for me, and I also use the [send via SMTP feature](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?ctx=%67mail&answer=140634) so that the from address is not spoofed.  100% legitimate.

Comment: The biggest issue for me is the non-robust tagging when you choose to forward instead of POP3. I like having tags for all my email accounts (e.g. `user1@example.com`, `user2@example.com`, etc.).