# Import external emails into Gmail only once per day at 8pm

Tags: gmail, email, outlook.com, pop3, imap

In a  Gmail account `example@gmail.com`, I'd like to import new emails from `activity2@gmail.com` (or from `activity2@hotmail.com`) **only once per day at 8pm**, to avoid being disturbed constantly at any time time of the day with the emails related to this activity.

The feature *Settings > Accounts and Import > Check email from other accounts* works, but it checks the email too often (once per hour). Is it possible to totally disable automatic hourly check? (Then I could trigger the check for new emails from API, once per day).

**How to do this only once per day?**

I'm ok to use Google Apps Script, to use an API from my server with a `cron`, etc.

What simple solutions are there?

---

Note: here it's precisely the opposite request :) :

- https://rakowski.pro/how-to-force-gmail-to-check-your-pop3-account-as-often-as-possible/
- [Is there a way to increase the rate at which Gmail fetches mail from another account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95579/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-rate-at-which-gmail-fetches-mail-from-another-acc?rq=1)
- [Can I control how often Gmail polls POP3 accounts for incoming mail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/can-i-control-how-often-gmail-polls-pop3-accounts-for-incoming-mail?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How can I increase the frequency Gmail checks other accounts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/how-can-i-increase-the-frequency-gmail-checks-other-accounts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hi Basj, FYI you could vote to reopen this question since you have more than 500 rep.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thanks! Done!